# JQuery Cookie not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I had a javascript Function showHide(shID) , which is a function to hide div and show content after clicked "read more" . Here is my Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/5xf72j4m/8/)

after added JQuery Cookie into this function , its seem like function showHide(shID) was gone , can anyone help me to fix it ? thanks I really need help . here my Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/j5dh67y3/2/)

I need to do smtg like this :First click on "readmore", hidden content will show,after set cookie and user come back to visit my page hidden content still showing .

```
<div id="wrap">
   <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');">
      <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg btn-block btn-u-dark-orange">
         Read More
      </button>
   </a>
   <div id="example" class="more">
      <iframe width="600" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BaPlMMlyM_0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JQuery Cookie  - it's plugin. And you need include it separately. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Hi demo ,Thanks for reply me , I not really sure with this too ,my first time to use JQuery cookie

Comment: please see this http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ I think you need to download and add library to project

Comment: yah .. i already done this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the script logic a little: show the content when `showhide-...` is set to `1`. Also I added a parameter to the `showHide` function: `setCookie`. When this is `false`, the cookie is no set/changed.

```
function showHide(setCookie) {
    var shID = $(this).data("showhide")
      , $shEl = $("#" + shID)
      , $showHide = $("#" + shID + '-show')
      ;

    if ($shEl.is(":hidden")) {
        if (setCookie !== false) {
            jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + shID, 1);
        }
        $showHide.hide();
        $shEl.show();
    } else {
        if (setCookie !== false) {
            jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + shID, 0);
        }
        $showHide.show();
        $shEl.hide();
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example-show").on("click", showHide);
    if (jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + "example") == '1') {
        showHide.call($("#example-show").get(0), false);
    }
});
```

To add an expire date, just pass the third argument to the `$.cookie` call:

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 30;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

(refer to [How to expire a cookie in 30 minutes using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1830246/1420197) for more information)

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ocukxdj4/4/)

Comment: Hi Ionica Bizau , really thanks for your help ! It's work fine for me ! However ,how can I set 1 day expire date for this ? Thanks ! =D

Comment: am I right ? if I wrote like this ?put 1 minute as testing http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/3Lzytvqy/4/   , what should I change in "foo" .

Comment: @lucas In your example (last jsfiddle link), the `example` cookie is set every time you load the page, but will expire after one minute.

Comment: I see , now I put 30mins for expired , but it's seem like not working ,$.cookie("example", "foo",  <<  do I need to change "foo" ? http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/3Lzytvqy/5/

Comment: I had put    $.cookie("example", "shID", { expires: date });  is it correct ? sorry I not really sure which one is my "cookie", "value" .

Comment: @lucas You have to understand what are the cookies, then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Answer (score 0):

Names of cookies are case sensitive and you have to read the same name of cookie which you set before. In your case you set 
`jQuery.cookie("showHide-"+shID, 1)` and check `jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + "example")`. 
"showHide-" and "showhide-" are mismatching.

**EDIT:**

```
    if (document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display != 'none') {
        // Set cookie when button has been clicked 
        jQuery.cookie("showhide-"+shID, 1);
        // ...
    } else {
        jQuery.cookie("showhide-"+shID, 0);
        // ...
    }

    if (jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + "example") == 1) {
        // Trigger button click if cookie is set 
        $("#example-show").trigger("click");
    }
```

Comment: Hi rba, thanks for your reply , means I just have to put "showhide" in "showHide" right ?  I had tried this before not working

Comment: Probably you just need to place your button trigger when cookie is set while you do it inversely. From you answer it seems you want to "set cookie and user come back to visit my page hidden content still showing" and in your comment in code you try to "// Cookie not set so show div".

Comment: yes , I need "set cookie and user come back to visit my page hidden content still showing"  ...sorry I not really understand , can you do a Fiddle for me as example ? I need for my side project , and I'm new in javascript too ..thanks rba,

Comment: Hi rba ,I had tried your code , its seem like not working ... can you help me to review ,am I wrote wrong ? thanks http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/vvhvhy36/5/